# wxPython ScrolledPanel not showing widgets as soon as I call any method on the panel

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

There are two panels (one is a ScrolledPanel) in another panel. The bottom one is the ScrolledPanel, as soon as I call any method on the ScrolledPanel, such as `panel.SetScrollRate(10, 10)` all the widgets disappear. Commenting out that line and all the widgets reappear. The top panel always displays fine.

I just found that if I add the line below in the InspectionTool it starts to work, but if I include the line in the actual code I get no widgets as before.
`obj.SetupScrolling(rate_x=10, rate_y=10, scrollToTop=False)`

```
class FieldEdit(wx.Panel):
    tmd = TomlMetaData()

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.title = '''Add/Remove Fields'''
        self._bg_color = (232, 213, 149)
        w_bg_color = (222, 237, 230)
        w_fg_color_0 = (50, 50, 204)
        w_fg_color_1 = (197, 75, 108)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(*self._bg_color))
        # Setup sizers.
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        # Setup panels.
        kwargs = {'g_sizer': sizer, 'bg_color': self._bg_color,
                  'w_bg_color': w_bg_color, 'w_fg_color_0': w_fg_color_0,
                  'w_fg_color_1': w_fg_color_1}
        panel_top = self._panel_top(kwargs)
        sizer.Add(panel_top, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 6)

    def _panel_top(self, kwargs):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        grid_sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(vgap=2, hgap=2)
        sizer.Add(grid_sizer, 0, wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, 6)
        w_bg_color = kwargs['w_bg_color']
        w_fg_color_0 = kwargs['w_fg_color_0']
        w_fg_color_1 = kwargs['w_fg_color_1']
        desc = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, self._description, style=0)
        desc.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(*w_fg_color_1))
        desc.SetFont(wx.Font(10, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL,
                             wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, 0, ''))
        grid_sizer.Add(desc, (0, 0), (1, 3), wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 6)

        edit_names = self._edit_names
        kwargs['edit_names'] = edit_names
        edit_names.insert(0, 'Choose the Page to Edit')
        combo_box = wx.ComboBox(panel, wx.ID_ANY, value=edit_names[0],
                                choices=edit_names, style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        combo_box.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(*w_bg_color))
        combo_box.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(*w_fg_color_0))
        combo_box.SetMinSize([196, 23])
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.selection_closure(kwargs), combo_box)
        grid_sizer.Add(combo_box, (1, 0), (1, 1),
                       wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALL, 6)

        field_desc = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Enter a new field name:",
                                   style=0)
        field_desc.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(*w_fg_color_0))
        field_desc.SetFont(
            wx.Font(10, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL,
                    wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, 0, ''))
        grid_sizer.Add(field_desc, (2, 0), (1, 1), wx.ALL, 6)

        field_name = wx.TextCtrl(panel,  wx.ID_ANY, "", style=wx.TE_LEFT)
        field_name.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(*w_bg_color))
        field_name.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(*w_fg_color_0))
        field_name.SetMinSize((200, 23))
        grid_sizer.Add(field_name, (2, 1), (1, 1), wx.ALL, 6)
        add_button = wx.Button(panel,  wx.ID_ANY, 'Add')
        add_button.SetMinSize((50, 23))
        add_button.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(*w_bg_color))
        add_button.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(*w_fg_color_0))
        add_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_button)
        grid_sizer.Add(add_button, (2, 2), (1, 1), wx.ALL, 6)

        line = wx.StaticLine(panel, wx.ID_ANY)
        line.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(*w_fg_color_0))
        grid_sizer.Add(line, (3, 0), (1, 3), wx.EXPAND | wx.BOTTOM, 2)
        return panel

    def _panel_bot(self, kwargs):
        panel = ScrolledPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        grid_sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(vgap=2, hgap=2)
        sizer.Add(grid_sizer, 0, wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, 6)
        w_fg_color_0 = kwargs['w_fg_color_0']
        w_fg_color_1 = kwargs['w_fg_color_1']
        widget_labels = kwargs['widget_labels']

        for idx, label in enumerate(widget_labels):
            label = label.replace(r'\n', '\n')
            widget = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, label)

            if label.endswith(':'):
                span = 1
                weight = 10
                color = w_fg_color_0
            else:
                span = 2
                weight = 12
                color = w_fg_color_1

            if '\n' in label:
                width = 46
            else:
                width = 23

            widget.SetFont(wx.Font(
                weight, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL,
                wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, 0, ''))
            widget.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(*color))
            widget.SetMinSize((-1, width))
            grid_sizer.Add(
                widget, (idx, 0), (1, span),
                wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM, 6)

        #panel.SetScrollRate(10, 10) # When uncommented the widgets do not display.

        kwargs['panel'] = panel
        return panel

    def selection_closure(self, kwargs):
        def get_selection(event):
            edit_names = kwargs['edit_names']
            chosen = event.GetString().lower()
            widget_labels = []

            if edit_names[0].lower() != chosen:
                items = self.tmd.panel_config.get(
                    chosen, {}).get('widgets', {})

                for value in items.values():
                    if (not isinstance(value, list)
                        or value[0] != 'StaticText'): continue
                    args = self._find_dict(value).get('args', [])
                    widget_labels.append(args[2])

                kwargs['widget_labels'] = widget_labels
                self._create_widgets(kwargs)
            else:
                self._destroy_panel(kwargs.get('panel'), kwargs.get('g_sizer'))

        return get_selection

    def _create_widgets(self, kwargs):
        g_sizer = kwargs['g_sizer']
        panel = kwargs.get('panel')
        # Destroy the previous panel if it exists.
        self._destroy_panel(panel, g_sizer)
        # Create a new panel.
        panel = self._panel_bot(kwargs)
        g_sizer.Add(panel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 6)

    def _destroy_panel(self, panel, g_sizer):
        if g_sizer and panel:
            g_sizer.Remove(1)
            panel.Destroy()
            g_sizer.Layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the primary issue. I had to do two things to get it to work properly.

First I added the line below at the end of the `_create_widgets` method. It seems I needed a delay before I tried to call `SetupScrolling` and 100ms did the trick.

```
        wx.CallLater(100, panel.SetupScrolling, rate_x=10, rate_y=10)
```

Second I had to create an event that runs when a resize event takes place. The line below was added to more or less the end of the `_panel_bot` method.

```
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.resize_closure(panel, grid_sizer))
```

I tend to use closures when calling events so I can pass other variables into the event. The event code is below.

```
    def resize_closure(self, panel, grid_sizer):
        def on_size_change(event):
            width, height = grid_sizer.GetMinSize()
            height += self.parent.statusbar_size[1]
            panel.SetSizeHints(width, height)

        return on_size_change
```

This seems to fix all the issues except one. I need to use a status bar at the bottom of the Frame, but when I scroll to the bottom of any panel the last widget is partially covered by the status bar. This is a different issue, however.